# How do developers load applications onto Windows 8 RT?

Tags: windows-8

Windows 8 'store' apps (the only kind supported on Windows RT) are meant to be installed via the Windows marketplace, but there are situations in which it would be useful to bypass this. For example, during beta testing, a developer might want to release an application to a limited audience before making it available in the store. Or maybe my friend writes something, and I'd like to load it onto my Surface?

How can I do this? Is there a mechanism where I can decide to install an application supplied directly by a developer?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, you friend should be able to acheieve this,since they know how to side-load their own applications.

Answer (score 4):

Developers can test their applications using a Developer License which they are able to obtain by using Visual Studio, it is free for them and allows them to run their application without it being published on the Windows Store.

You can read more about the [Developer License](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974578.aspx).

If your friend writes an app and you want to test it on your surface, you will have to obtain a Developers License and also the source of the app from your friend so you can build it and run it on your Surface.

Comment: The author could in theory just use the friend's developer key.

Answer (score 0):

No, those sort of applications will not be supported on the Surface RT or Windows RT devices. Hence, if your friend writes something that you would want installed on your Surface, he/she would first have to post it to the Windows 8 Store, get it approved and published and only then can you download it to your device.

Comment: This is slightly false.  There is no reason his friend couldn't load the application on Misha's surface for him, using the friends developer key, the frend might not have a surface themselfs.